# Insert an external PDF file in LyX file

Tags: graphics, lyx, pdf

I am trying to add my 10 pages external PDF file in between the LyX document. But when I convert my whole file in PDF version the external file only shows its first page. What should I do now?

Comment: How do you include this external file under LyX?

Comment: Insert->File->external material

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you Insert > File > External Material, you should choose the PDF pages template:

[image]

Note how it mentions the option `pages=-` in order to include the entire document. That is, by default, this template (using the [`pdfpages` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages)) only includes the first page. Therefore, under the LaTeX and LyX options tabs, enter

[image]

This should include the entire PDF in your document output. LyX will still only display the first page as a frame of reference.